# Macro: How to suppress Texclipse error

Tags: macros, includegraphics, eclipse

For easy and versatile integration of pictures and graphics in my documents I found a nice solution in [this post 'newcommand for pictures'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242271/newcommand-for-pictures).

Due to unorthodox order of `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` in the code I always have Texclipse (pdflatex, oxygen) showing errors at these lines (see code below}: `\begin{figure} does not have matching end; at least one unbalanced begin-end`. However, the code compiles with fine output.

How can I avoid getting these error messages with the functionality of the code pointed out in the [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242271/newcommand-for-pictures)? If the code is fine, how can I suppress the errors messages in Texclipse?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Between the \ExplSyntaxOn the code is copied from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242271/newcommand-for-pictures
\ExplSyntaxOn

% the user level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\addpic}{m}
 {
  \group_begin: % localize the changes to the variables
  \forthisdoc_pic:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

% the key-value interface
\keys_define:nn { forthisdoc/pic }
 {
  placement .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_placement_tl,
  placement .initial:n = htp,
  width .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_width_tl,
  width .initial:n = 1,
  options .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_options_tl,
  image .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_image_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_shortcaption_tl,
  label .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_label_tl,
 }

% the main command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \forthisdoc_pic:n
 {
  % set the keys from the argument
  \keys_set:nn { forthisdoc/pic } { #1 }
  % start the figure environment
  \__forthisdoc_start_figure:V \l_forthisdoc_pic_placement_tl
  \centering
  % include the image
  \__forthisdoc_pic_image:VVV
    \l_forthisdoc_pic_width_tl % the text width fraction
    \l_forthisdoc_pic_options_tl % other options
    \l_forthisdoc_pic_image_tl % the image name
  % the caption
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_forthisdoc_pic_shortcaption_tl
   {
    \caption{\l_forthisdoc_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   {
    \caption[\l_forthisdoc_pic_shortcaption_tl]{\l_forthisdoc_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   % the label
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l_forthisdoc_pic_label_tl
    {
     \label{\l_forthisdoc_pic_label_tl}
    }
   % end the figure environment
   \end{figure}
}

% syntactic sugar: we want some token lists to be expanded before usage
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__forthisdoc_start_figure:n
 {
  \begin{figure}[#1]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__forthisdoc_start_figure:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__forthisdoc_pic_image:nnn
 {
  \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,#2]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__forthisdoc_pic_image:nnn { VVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
An example picture is shown in \ref{label}.
\addpic{
  placement=bp,
  width=0.2,
  options={angle=90},
  image=example-image-a,
  caption=Rotated image,
  label=label,
  shortcaption=In the text the image is rotated!,
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just put the code in `mypic.sty` and use `\usepackage{mypic}` in your docuemnt, then you can easily re-use in many documents and your editor will never see the code at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) pointed out, putting the code into a *.sty file does it. E.g. a working example is

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{addpic}
\begin{document}
\addpic{
  width=0.3,
  image=example-image,
  caption={This is an example image, and a comma in the caption},
  label=one,
}
\end{document}
```

with the sty file containing

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{addpic}[2018/12/03 addpic by tex.stackexchange example]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

% Between the \ExplSyntaxOn the code is copied from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242271/newcommand-for-pictures
\ExplSyntaxOn

% the user level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\addpic}{m}
 {
  \group_begin: % localize the changes to the variables
  \forthisdoc_pic:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

% the key-value interface
\keys_define:nn { forthisdoc/pic }
 {
  placement .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_placement_tl,
  placement .initial:n = htp,
  width .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_width_tl,
  width .initial:n = 1,
  options .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_options_tl,
  image .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_image_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_shortcaption_tl,
  label .tl_set:N = \l_forthisdoc_pic_label_tl,
 }

% the main command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \forthisdoc_pic:n
 {
  % set the keys from the argument
  \keys_set:nn { forthisdoc/pic } { #1 }
  % start the figure environment
  \__forthisdoc_start_figure:V \l_forthisdoc_pic_placement_tl
  \centering
  % include the image
  \__forthisdoc_pic_image:VVV
    \l_forthisdoc_pic_width_tl % the text width fraction
    \l_forthisdoc_pic_options_tl % other options
    \l_forthisdoc_pic_image_tl % the image name
  % the caption
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_forthisdoc_pic_shortcaption_tl
   {
    \caption{\l_forthisdoc_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   {
    \caption[\l_forthisdoc_pic_shortcaption_tl]{\l_forthisdoc_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   % the label
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l_forthisdoc_pic_label_tl
    {
     \label{\l_forthisdoc_pic_label_tl}
    }
   % end the figure environment
   \end{figure}
}

% syntactic sugar: we want some token lists to be expanded before usage
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__forthisdoc_start_figure:n
 {
  \begin{figure}[#1]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__forthisdoc_start_figure:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__forthisdoc_pic_image:nnn
 {
  \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,#2]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__forthisdoc_pic_image:nnn { VVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

[Here is some help for a good place of the sty file.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)