# Macro to create figures with pgfkeys

Tags: macros, pgfkeys, includegraphics

I am trying to extend the example mentioned [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242271/newcommand-for-pictures) to write a macro that takes several arguments (width of the figure, caption, label + N file names) and produces a figure including those N figures. N may be greater than 6, so the approach followed in that post won't work, because it would go beyond the 9 arguments limit.

I was trying instead to use \pgfkeys in the following way

```
\pgfkeys{/myfigure/.is family, /myfigure,
    caption/.store in =\mycaption,
    width/.store in =\mywidth,
    label/.store in =\mylabel,
    figA/.estore in=\figA,
...
    figN/.estore in=\figN,

}


\newcommand\myfigure[1]{
    \pgfkeys{myfigure,#1}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{\figA}
...
        \includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{\figN}
        \caption{\mycaption}
        \label{\mylabel}
    \end{figure}

}
```

And calling it as

```
\myfigure[width=\textwidth,label=kk,caption=caption,figA={plot_name.pdf}}
```

However, this won't work because of the underscore in the plot_name.pdf. What I'm I missing here?

Also I would be interested in this macro reading an arbitrary number of figures.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! It should be `\pgfkeys{/myfigure/.cd,#1}` instead of `\pgfkeys{myfigure,#1}`, i.e. with a `/` and the `/.cd` is IMHO cleaner. (Obviously I cannot tell if this solves all problems because you post only fragments.)

Comment: Thanks! this solved the problem!